# Exchange 2010: Remove Administrator Mailbox

Tags: exchange, mailbox, remove

How can I remove the Administrator Mailbox from Exchange 2010?
I don't want to delete the whole user account because I need Administrator to access the Server, but Administrator shouldn't have any mail addresses assigned.

Background:
We use Eset Mail Security which is getting licenced per mailbox count. There is also a tool from ESET to check current mailbox count: http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2425
To avoid paying for unused mailboxes, I want to disable Administrator's (and also other unused) mail boxes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *seems* like a bad reason to remove the Administrator's mailbox. The yearly per-user pricing on ESET's Mail Security for Exchange is under $30 in blocks up to 5 users. It goes down as your numbers increase. How many users are you licensed for? Are you really that constrained?

Either way, to remove the administrator mailbox, something like this should work:

```
get-mailbox -id administrator | disable-mailbox
```

Comment: Could you specify a bit more, why it would be a bad idea to disable Admin's mailbox?
Because I'm the Admin and have my own user with mail address. Or do some programs rely on Admin's mailbox?